# How can I get exact division of decimals for more than 9 digits?

Tags: java, floating-accuracy

When doing this

```
float d = (106108048) / (float)10;
```

The output is `1.0610805E7`, but I need exactly **`10610804.8`**. What is correct way to do that?

On Hacker Rank, I was solving the following problem: You are given a number N, you need to print the number of positions where digits exactly divides N.

Input:

```
1
106108048
```

Result:

```
5
```

My Solution:

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.*;
 import java.math.*;


    public class Solution{

        public static void main(String[] args){
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            int p = 0;
            boolean check = true;
            while(sc.hasNext()){
                if(check){
                    check= false;
                    sc.next();
                }
                Integer number = sc.nextInt();
                String snumner = number.toString();
                int q = 1;
                int j = 0;
                for(int i = 0 ; i< snumner.length();i++ ){
                            q = q *10;
                            p = q;
                   System.out.println("p:"+p)
                   System.out.println("number:"+number);
                    float d = (number)/(float)p;//problem is here
                    System.out.println("ddd:"+d);
                    String ss = String.valueOf(d);
                    System.out.println("SS:"+ss);
                    int index = ss.indexOf('.');
                    System.out.println("in"+index);
                    System.out.println("VV"+ss.charAt(index+1));
                    String newn = " " + ss.charAt(index+1);
                    int sss= Integer.parseInt(newn.trim());
                   System.out.println("SSS"+sss);
                    if(sss != 0){
                    if(number%sss ==0){
                        j++;
                     }
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("no:"+j);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What output? How are you viewing it?

Comment: `double` gives you better precision than `float` but they are both **not** suitable for decimal arithmetics

Comment: Want exact answers? Use [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html). Want better answers, but not at the cost of performance? Use `double`.

Comment: double also is giving same result .I am looking to get like in math .

Comment: @Coder2007: Give more code then. It may be that there's some implicit casting to `float` going on when you print it.

Comment: The problem here is how it's being printed not the accuracy of the float. Try `String.format("%f", d);`

Comment: Given a requirement "You are given a number N, you need to print the number of positions where digits exactly divides N", I would first and formost *reject* it immediately as "define the requirement properly, then we talk again". I suspect you don't need any *floating* point here, modulo operator with int would do. But given the gibberish requirement I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `DecimalFormat`. However, another better option is to use `BigDecimal` which provides a method out-of-the box:

```
BigDecimal value = BigDecimal.valueOf(106108048).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(10));
System.out.println(value.toPlainString());
```

Note that, given `BigDecimal` class has arbitrary precision, you might well get long string there. You can also round that out as per your needs.

Comment: In fact, you *need* to round, because otherwise the decimal representation of that division is not just long, it's infinite.  If you try to do it precisely then the `divide()` method will throw an exception.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Oh! Didn't try it :)

Comment: @JohnBollinger I tried it, and got exact output as required without rounding. But I have seen for some cases, exception been thrown.

Answer (score 5):

Use java's [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) instead. That class is designed for fixed point arithmetic and will provide better accuracy.

To quote the documentation on BigDecimal:

> Immutable, arbitrary-precision signed decimal numbers. A BigDecimal consists of an arbitrary precision integer unscaled value and a 32-bit integer scale.

An example:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.MathContext;

public class BigDecimalExample{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigDecimal dividend = BigDecimal.valueOf( 106108048 );
    BigDecimal divisor = BigDecimal.valueOf( 10 );
    BigDecimal result = dividend.divide( divisor, MathContext.DECIMAL64 );
    System.out.println( result.toPlainString( ) );
  }
}
```

This will print out:

```
10610804.8
```

Note that this example uses [MathContext.DECIMAL64](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/MathContext.html#DECIMAL64) as a way to pass a precision and rounding mode to the [divide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide%28java.math.BigDecimal,%20java.math.MathContext%29) method. This sets a precision and rounding mode matching the IEEE 754R Decimal64 format, 16 digits, and a rounding mode of `HALF_EVEN`, the IEEE 754R default.

You can tweak the precision and [RoundingMode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html) by [constructing a MathContext object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/MathContext.html#MathContext%28int,%20java.math.RoundingMode%29) if needed.

It is always best to pass a `MathContext` parameter in the `divide` method for arbitrary calculations. The [divide(BigDecimal divisor)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide%28java.math.BigDecimal%29) method will throw an `ArithmeticException` if the exact quotient does not have a terminating decimal expansion.

Answer (score 2):

Use `double`.

PS: floating point cant be exact anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Increase precise by using `double`. If it isn't enough, use `BigDecimal`. In your case:

```
double d = 106108048d / 10d;
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double d = (106108048) / (double)10;
    System.out.println(d);
    System.out.println(new DecimalFormat("#.#").format(d));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your final goal is to write/show the value as String, use in the end the function `String.format`.